# Simple jQuery div toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to create a simple hide and show div toggle, though it's not working. I'm not sure what the issue is -- I have the div initially `display:none`, then when the `course-info-toggle` class is clicked, it should turn to `display:block`, and `transition` down.

Any ideas?

```js
/* Toggle on course detail sections */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.course-info-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('.show');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-content.show {
  display: block;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle-wrap">
  <div class="course-info-toggle">
    <p id="course-details-toggle-font">COURSE OBJECTIVES</p>
    <img src="img/course-down-arrow.png" align="course-down-arrow">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get any errors in the browse'rs console?

Comment: This `transition: left 0.3s linear;` works only if left property is defined in initial and final rules.

Comment: change $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('.show') to $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show')

Comment: solution updated for transition and animation

Comment: Confused. What have you changed regarding animated transition in the code?

Comment: Removed display. Added visibility. And opacity. Created a keyframe. Called that keyframe from animation property. You can read more on transitions at http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the dot in the toggleClass

It should be

```
$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');
```

and not like `.toggleClass('.show')`

You want to add animation and transition both, it seems. Use keyframes for animation. Display property does not appear to be working with transition.

[Css transition from display none to display block, navigation with subnav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772442/css-transition-from-display-none-to-display-block-navigation-with-subnav)

[Slide in from left CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159490/slide-in-from-left-css-animation)

**Solution**: You can change your css classes to this. Now, you can work over on it in different ways.

```
.toggle-content.show {
   visibility: visible;
     position: relative;
   opacity: 1;
     animation: leftSlide 2s forwards;
}

.toggle-content {
 opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  transition: opacity 5s, visibility 2ms;
}

@keyframes leftSlide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-900px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

To make it slide down, you can use `translateY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `.show` to only `show` & add `!important` to `display:block`

```js
/* Toggle on course detail sections */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.course-info-toggle').click(function() {

    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-content.show {
  display: block !important;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
  <div class="course-info-toggle">
    <p id="course-details-toggle-font">COURSE OBJECTIVES</p>
    <img src="img/course-down-arrow.png" align="course-down-arrow">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('.show');
```

to line

```
$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should, unless i am mistaken and this is not a typo

`$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('.show');`

You should not be using '.show' it should be

`$('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');`

You dont have to use .class name as per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) . It is working properly IMHO if you do this.

you can check out the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hocabbo1/) . Didnt make any changes except the one mentioned above.

Comment: Okay, works, but doesn't do the transition as defined in the css class??

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.course-info-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');
 });
});
```

```css
.toggle-content.show {
 display: block;
    transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

.toggle-content {
 display: none;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 padding: 1rem;
 margin-right:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
 <div class="course-info-toggle">
  <p id="course-details-toggle-font">COURSE OBJECTIVES</p>
  <img src="img/course-down-arrow.png" align="course-down-arrow">
 </div>
 <div class="toggle-content">
  <p>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
  <p>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
  </p>
 </div>                          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass accepts a string so please use the following:

```
.toggleClass('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Toggle on course detail sections */
$('.course-info-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.toggle-content.show {
  display: block;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
  <div class="course-info-toggle">
    <p id="course-details-toggle-font">COURSE OBJECTIVES</p>
    <img src="img/course-down-arrow.png" align="course-down-arrow">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      <p> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled”<br>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```